# How to perform A-B set operation in C program using builtin library

Tags: c, arrays, set-operations

I am new to C language. Suppose I have two arrays `a` and `b`

```
int a[10] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0 };
int b[10] = { 1,3,5,7,9 };
```

and I want to perform `a-b` so that I can get all elements of array `a` which are not present in array `b`. In ruby or python, I can just simply do `a-b` and get the result. Here is my c code that I have tried but my code which is not working.I am looking for a C library that does this operation for me in a line.I have also found this [library](http://www.mission-base.com/peter/source/pbl/doc/set.html) but not sure how to implement it. Any kind of help is appreciated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define Max 100

int m,n,i,j,k,p,q,r,s;
int flag=1;
char char1,char2,char3;
void Difference(int *,int *,int ,int);
void Display2(char ,char ,int );

int a[10] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0 };
int b[10] = { 1,3,5,7,9 };
int c[10];

void Difference(int *a1,int *b1,int m1,int n1)
{
    q=0;
    p=0;
    i=0;
    for(k=0;k<m1;k++){
        flag=1;
        for(j=0;j<n1;j++){
            if(b1[j]==a1[k]){
                flag=1;
                q++;
                break;
            }
            else{
                flag=0;
            }
        }
        if(flag==0){
            c[p]=a1[k];
            p++;
        }
    }
}

void Display2(char ac,char bc,int m1)
{
    printf("\nThe Difference Of Two Sets i.e '%c - %c' Is : { ",ac,bc);
    r = m1 - q;
    for(p=0;p<r;p++){
        printf("%2d",c[p]);
    }
    printf(" }");
}


int main(){
    Difference(a,b,m,n);
    Display2('A','B',m);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Off-topic. Read some [introduction to algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms)

Comment: BTW: use `\n` at end (not start) of `printf` format string. Compile with all warnings and debug info: `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). **Use the debugger `gdb`**

Comment: _"I have tried but not got any success"_ is not a valid problem statement.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious question language updated.

Comment: _" I have tried but my code is not working"_ isn't a valid problem statement either.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious please check now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can guess, you forgot to initialize your `m` and `n` variables with proper values.
Add `m = 10; n = 5;` before calling `Difference` and your code will work.

I also suggest you to write more readable code: better naming for variables, use some spaces and avoid global variables.

**Edit:**
In C++ you can write:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <set>

int main() {
    std::set<int> a = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    std::set<int> b = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
    std::set<int> c;

    std::set_difference(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), std::inserter(c, c.begin()));

    for (const auto item : c) 
        std::cout << item << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Detail information about `std::set_difference` can be found [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_difference)

Comment: Thanks it worked. Can you please suggest any builtin library for doing the same operation?

Comment: No, I don't know any for C

Comment: is there any library for c++?

Comment: There is `std::set` in C++. You can use it together with `std::remove_if`. You will need to `#include <algorithm> #include <set>`